# Logic App recurrence workflow: add condition to set variable every 2 days

Tags: workflow, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I have a recurrence workflow which triggers every 2 hours.
By default, variable x is set to 111.

Now, I want to add a condition: every 2 days (48 hours), the variable x is set to 999.

For example:

```
12 am: x = 111
2 am : x = 111
...
...
8 pm : x = 111
10 pm: x = 111
12 am: x = 111
2 am : x = 111
...
...
8 pm : x = 111
10 pm: x = 111
12 am: x = 999
2 am : x = 111
...
```

Is there a possibility of doing this checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this in Azure Logic Apps by using a combination of recurrence, date and time functions, and condition actions.

1. **Recurrence Trigger**: Start with a "Recurrence" trigger that runs every 2 hours.
2. **Initialize Variable**: Add an "Initialize Variable" action to create the variable `x` with a default value of `111`.
3. **Check Date and Time**: Use a condition to check the current time. The expression to check if the current time is exactly 12 am (midnight) and if the day is even (indicating every other day) would look like this:

```
@and(equals(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'HH'), '00'), equals(mod(dayOfYear(utcNow()), 2), 0))
```

4. **Set Variable Based on Condition**:

   - If the condition is `true` (it's an even day and currently midnight), set variable `x` to `999`.
   - If the condition is `false`, set variable `x` to `111`.
5. **Next Actions**: After this, you can add any other actions you need based on the value of `x`.